# TRIANGLE ALGORITHM

Tags: java, algorithm, logic

1

2 3

4 5 4

3 2 1 2

3 4 5 4 3

I want to make a triangle like that. I have tried making the triangle and the numbers but the numbers doesn't fit the triangle so the output isn't as expected. Please help.

Example input: n = 5;

1) This is the code to make the triangle.

```
int k = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                if (j <= i) {
                    System.out.print("* ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("  ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

2) This is the code to make the numbers.

```
int k = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    if (k == 5) {
                        break;
                    }
                    System.out.print(k + " ");
                    k++;
                } else if (i % 2 != 0) {
                    if (k == 1) {
                        break;
                    }
                    System.out.print(k + " ");
                    k--;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Instead of printing `*` you can create a method which will return numbers in sequence 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 ... . So after creating such method simply change `System.out.print("* ");` to `System.out.print(generator.getNumber() + " ");`

Comment: @Pshemo Can you show me the code? I still don't understand how to combine the numbers and the triangle shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to print a number of rows, with each row printed having the same number of values as the row number. If we were printing `*`'s, it would be easy:

```
static void printTriangle(int rowCount) {
    for (int row = 1; row <= rowCount; row++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
            System.out.print("* ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

*printTriangle(5)*

```
* 
* * 
* * * 
* * * * 
* * * * *
```

Instead of printing `*`'s, we want the values to come from a repeating sequence of `1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 ...`.

The sequence is 8 long, so if we take an ever-increasing number `a`, starting at 0, and calculate remainder when dividing by 8, i.e. `b = a % 8`, we get a repeating sequence of `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ...`. If we then calculate distance from `4`, using `c = Math.abs(4 - b)`, we get `4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 ...`. If we subtract that from `5`, i.e. `d = 5 - c`, we get `1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 ...`, i.e. the desired sequence.

```
static void printTriangle(int rowCount) {
    int a = 0;
    for (int row = 1; row <= rowCount; row++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            int b = a % 8;
            int c = Math.abs(4 - b);
            int d = 5 - c;
            System.out.print(d + " ");
            a++;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The code can be reduced to:

```
static void printTriangle(int rowCount) {
    for (int seq = 0, row = 1; row <= rowCount; row++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++, seq++)
            System.out.print((5 - Math.abs(4 - seq % 8)) + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

*printTriangle(10)*

```
1 
2 3 
4 5 4 
3 2 1 2 
3 4 5 4 3 
2 1 2 3 4 5 
4 3 2 1 2 3 4 
5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 
5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 
4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 4 3
```

For the advanced version, we can make the max value printed be dynamic too:

```
static void printTriangle(int rowCount, int maxValue) {
    String fmt = "%" + String.valueOf(maxValue).length() + "s ";
    for (int row = 1, seq = 0; row <= rowCount; row++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++, seq++)
            System.out.printf(fmt, (maxValue - Math.abs(maxValue - 1 - seq % (maxValue * 2 - 2))));
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

*printTriangle(5, 5)*

```
1 
2 3 
4 5 4 
3 2 1 2 
3 4 5 4 3
```

*printTriangle(20, 14)*

```
 1 
 2  3 
 4  5  6 
 7  8  9 10 
11 12 13 14 13 
12 11 10  9  8  7 
 6  5  4  3  2  1  2 
 3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
11 12 13 14 13 12 11 10  9 
 8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  2  3 
 4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 
13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2 
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 
14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1 
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 13 12 
11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  2  3  4  5  6 
 7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5 
 4  3  2  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 13 
12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 
 9 10 11 12 13 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  2
```